# I found possible security weak point, but don't know how to fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

Without removing this function at all.

I have form input, but rather than rendering view on validation fail without redirect, I redirect user to `new` page, but store his input in `Redis`, so don't loose errors messages and his actual entries:

```
  def create_list
     result=super
     if result[:all_records_saved]
      redirect_to program_stream_path(@stream.program, @stream)
     else
      redirect_to new_students_list_stream_path(@stream, :invalid_entry_id=>result[:id])
    end
  end
```

Where I pass invalid entry to method `redis_store` (which adds redis session)

```
def redis_store(invalid_entries)
  if $redis.exists("invalid_entries_ids")
    id = $redis.incr("invalid_entries_ids")
  else
    $redis.set("invalid_entries_ids", 0, ex: 600)
    id = 0
  end
  invalid_entries.each do |entry|
    $redis.multi do
      $redis.rpush("invalid_entries_attr:#{id}", entry[0])
      $redis.rpush("invalid_entries_errors:#{id}", entry[1])
      $redis.expire("invalid_entries_attr:#{id}", 600)
      $redis.expire("invalid_entries_errors:#{id}", 600)
    end
  end
  id
end
```

So user is redirected back, with `params[:invalid_entry_id]`, then other method fetches data from `redis` using this id.

**Issue**

I just understood, that if someone gets this redirect:

```
/edit-students-list?invalid_entry_id=1
```

He can change it to

```
/edit-students-list?invalid_entry_id=0
```

Or any id smaller than he actually got, and access to data he didn't meant to have access to.

That is not something big, but I would like to avoid it without removing all effort put to get this function working.

I notice that Rails `flash` doesn't need any params or external pointer to find out which flash belongs to which request. How I can implement this in my redis store/get functions? Or any other solution?

Comment: since GET requests passes parameters in the URL, have you considered using another HTTP method that doesnt use URL params, like POST?

Comment: You could do like the above comment says and get rid of using url params. You could also push a user id to redis, and in the controller, check to make sure the user entering the url is associated with the `invalid_entry_id` value.

Comment: @Haymaker87, first option is quite bad in my opinion as user refreshes page after redirect for some reason he'll loose his entry, on which he spent a lot of time. But i found another solution which is using `flash[invalid_entry_id]` and it seems to pass all my rspec